# Невозможно создать базу данных на Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

На WebAPI (.Net 3, VS19, SqlServer 2014, EntityCore 5) проекте не удаётся создать базу данных после старта проекта. Кто нибудь сталкивался с этим?
СТрока подключение:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=PLATINUM-ПК\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=PaySystem;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
```

Строка создание БД:

```
 public Context(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
            base.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
```

Ошибка:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:
> SNI_PN11, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

Comment: Попробуйте без указания имени компьютера: `Data Source=.\\SQLExpress`

Comment: Сервер с таким именем присутствует: `PLATINUM-ПК\\SQLEXPRESS`? Вы вообще устанавливали SqlExpress? Дело в том, что по умолчанию вместе с Visual Studio ставится LocalDB. Соответственно, строка подключения должна быть: `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb`

Comment: PLATINUM-ПК\SQLEXPRESS(ИМя сервера, виндовс аутнтификация)  ввожу для входа на SSMS. Через менеджер заходит а на проект не подключается

Comment: `var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PLATINUM-ПК\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=PaySystem;Trusted_Connection=True;"); con.Open();` - так соединение происходит?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить свой код следующим образом

```
public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options)
        {
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
```

Вот ссислка где расписано более детально
https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/12.1.php

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Да, исправил, благодарю за подсказку.

Comment: нет не помогло, столько вариантов пробовал

Comment: А Вы уже сделали миграцию? А то по сути БД создаетя именно когда она делается.

Comment: Ещё могу добавить.  Вот ссилка на которую я ориентировался при создании БД https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/2.15.php  , я так понимаю что у вас Code First, поэтому можете сразу смотреть раздел "Миграция".   Ну и на самый крайний случай есть видео  которое мне помогло создать БД (желательно посмотреть всё, но само создание на 18:00 примерно) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqmHCbVmpFA&list=PLzBCKSyQEHOWprnModVfJSfBqpzxQ4R16&index=7&ab_channel=RuslanScherbakov-kursoftru

Comment: огромное спасибо, смотрю сейчас

Comment: Как уже здесь было сказано, по степени убывания вероятностей, на первом месте стоит группа причин, связанных с доступом на вашей локальной машине, к SQL серверу (некорректный путь, запрет для доступа на уровне операционной системы и прочие проблемы).  Далее проблемы c Entity Framework Core (DbContext, создание миграций и их передача в БД). Далее возможно что не все пакеты для EF Core и SQL установлены в вашем проекте.  Вот [видео](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm_HvURobtaz8GrLaI-iQhhc) из курса по ASP.NET Core MVC(.NET 5), где подробно приводится пример создания БД.